# Two functions doing the exact same thing, alias?

Tags: c++, function

In a derived class I have a function called evaluate() (it's a virtual in the base class). In this derived class i also have a function set_value() and hence i want get_value() as well. get_value() should return the exact same thing as evaluate()

Is there anyway to say that a call to get_value is a call to evaluate()? With some sort of alias keyword?

I don't know if this exists or what it would be called, I have searched and nothing found.

Maybe I shoud do:

```
inline double Variable::get_value() const
{
    return evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Use inline and optimazations enabled and I guarantee no performance decrease.

Comment: How do I enable optimization? I am using command line g++ (Windows atm)

Comment: Use the `-O` command line flag (or `-O2`, `-O3`; see the GCC manual for details).

Comment: I propose writing `return Variable::evaluate();`. To inhibit the virtual call mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there are no aliases in C++ you're searching for. Sure, that is the way:

```
double Variable::get_value() const
{
    return evaluate();
}
```

On the other hand you could make `get_value()` function in a superclass and let it do the same thing if it is your design requirement.

---

The another advantage of implementing `get_value()` this way with bare hands is to provide an opportunity to involve additional logic. In case your `evaluate()` will get more and more CPU time you might implement simple caching in-place.

Comment: There is no advantage to using the inline keyword but using it adds complexity for the linker thus best advice is not to use unless it is needed.

Comment: @LokiAstari Could you please elaborate on that? As far as I know, the `inline` storage class indicates, as in "hints", that the function should be inlined but the compiler is free to ignore that. How does this make linking any more complex?

Comment: @HonkyTonk: An `inline` function is usually in a header file. If it is not actually inlined (because it is a hint only) then each compilation unit (object file) that includes the header file will have a copy of the function. During the link phase when the linker converts all the compilation units into an executable the linker must know that there can be several version of the same function. How it deals with this is outside the scope of the language but I suspect that it makes things harder.

Comment: @LokiAstari The linker deals with symbol resolution using scope, as one would expect. And if two functions that have the same type and name share the same scope, the linker will complain. If the `inline` function resides in a header file (but is not inlined) and has visibility that reaches outside of the compilation unit, the same rules apply if the linker has to find this specific symbol from another compilation unit. So, I'd say your suspicion is unfounded since the rules are deterministic and not too complex unless you venture into using the address of an `inline` function.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: Which version of the `inline void plop() {/*do Complex shit*/}` does the linker choose when it has multiple definitions in different compilation units. Have not myself seen where this is defined in the standard.